# Show that $\frac{x-1}{x \ln x}$ is bounded at the neighbourhood of $1$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $\dfrac{x-1}{x\ln x}$ is bounded at the neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at the neighborhood of 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Recall that the logarithm satisfies the inequalities

$$\frac {x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

Comment: The simplest way to show that the limit in 1 exist. Thank you.

Comment: @MiKiDe You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Show that the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }\ \dfrac{x-1}{x\ln x}$$

exists.

Using L'hopital:

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }\ \dfrac{x-1}{x\ln x} \\
=\lim_{x\to 1} \ \dfrac{1}{\ln(x)+1} =1$$

Comment: Why does the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ show that the function is bounded at the neighborhood of 1?

Comment: @MiKiDe Sorry I am stupid, we see limit $x\to 1$. If it exists, then the $f$ must be continuous and bounded in neighbourhood.

Comment: No, continuity doesn't follow from the finite existence of the limit. If **it is defined that** $\;f(1)=1\;$ , with $\;f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x\log x}\;$ , then  yes: $\;f\;$ continuous at $\;x=1\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry sir I said continuous in the neighbourhood .. of 1.

Comment: @samjoe There is not *the* neighborhood...and again: that continuity in *any neighborhood* doesn't follow.

Comment: @DonAntonio So that we can just say it is bounded?

Comment: @samjoe That we can say, yes.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your answer, helped me to understand